# ¿Cómo puede desaparecer varios PictureBox después de hacer contacto con ellos?

Tags: c#, formularios, windows

En este momento estoy haciendo una "imitación" del juego Pacman, como ya sabrán después de que Pacman se come las esferas estas desaparecen. Para simular esas esferas coloqué barios pictureBox, cómo puedo hacer que después de que Pacman las intercepte estas desaparezcan (Tengo más de 30 PictureBox para las esferas). 
Gracias!!
(Desarrollando en Windows Forms)

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente tenes que localizar el pictureBox y ocultarlo con pictureBox1.Hide() o en el caso de no volver a utilizarlo podes usar pictureBox1.Dispose() que libera los recursos del pictureBox